# ubuntu 16.04.1L iso burner incomplete

Tags: boot

Just downloaded and burnt iso to dvd. When i open the folder all files are there except the ubuntu icon. I cannot boot. Appreciate some assistance.

Comment: When you open the folder? Did you burn as ISO?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you are trying to make a **bootable usb drive**, then do:

Insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space
Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator
Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app

Find the Startup Disk Creator
Click 'Other' to choose the downloaded ISO file if it isn’t found automatically, select the file and click 'Open'

Select the ISO
Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk' and then 'Yes'

Confirm USB stick
That's it! When the process completes, you'll be ready to restart your computer and begin installing Ubuntu

Writing the ISO to disk